# "Aero glass does not know how to hook your version of dwm (0x8)"

Tags: windows-10, aero

I want to have the aero theme on my Windows 10 but this happens....

I downloaded this file:

[image]

then this appeared while installing:

[image]

I don't know what to do....

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit Version 1511 (OS Build 10586, 494)

Debug log:

```
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x978:0x980] Installing DWM hook...
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x978:0x980] User: SYSTEM
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x978:0x980] Module: C:\AeroGlass\DWMGlass.dll
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1560] Donation key not loaded (2 - The system           cannot find the file specified.)
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1560] Machine ID:    BRYGOJLIAPPQULUI6KCQL624BLRLW2ZK6YLQTYVQRLVECBIQ
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1560] Hook (USER32.dll!DrawTextW from udwm.dll) installed
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1560] Hook (GDI32.dll!CreateBitmap from udwm.dll) installed
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1560] Hook (GDI32.dll!CreateRoundRectRgn from udwm.dll) installed
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1560] Aero Glass for Win8.1+ 1.4.5.520 x64 correctly loaded (C:\AeroGlass\DWMGlass.dll).
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1538] DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: .;C:\AeroGlass\symbols
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1538] Loading settings (flags = 0x3) from HKEY 0x0000000000000404 for session #1
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1538] dwmcore.dll version 10.0.10586.494
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1538] udwm.dll version 10.0.10586.494
[2016-07-17 10:39:47][0x12CC:0x1538] DWM incompatibility error 0x8
```

Comment: What build of Windows 10 do you have? "This version is for Win8.1 6.3.9600 and for Win10 up to 10.0.10586."

Comment: share the debug.log from the Glass8 folder

Comment: @DavidPostill Version 1511 (OS Build 10586, 494)

Comment: @magicandre1981 please look at the debug log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you don't use Glass8 with a donation.key, so the tool doesn't automatically download the debug symbols (PDB) for all DWM related DLLs when the tool itself doesn't have a hardcoded patching pattern for a specific DLL version.

> [**What are the DWM symbols and where to get them?/ I see "Your DWM is incompatible" message. What to do?**](http://glass8.eu/guide#symbols)
>  Aero Glass for Win8.x+ works by
> injecting re-implemented code into several DWM functions. This can be
> achieved only when the absolute location of each function is known.
> These locations are described in special files called "program
> database" and you can recognize them by their .PDB extension. They
> contain set of all public DWM variables and functions (which are
> called symbols) together with their memory offsets (relative
> locations) and other information. Aero Glass for Win8.x+ is able to
> load these files from "symbols" directory stored in your Aero Glass
> installation directory, find appropriate symbol and compute absolute
> memory location.
>
> Since Aero Glass for Win8.x knows how each DWM function should look
> like, it is able to find them without the need of the program
> databases. Thus, in normal situation, user should not bother about it
> at all. **However, in some rare situations (e.g. some Windows update
> changes the look of the function), it may happen that known symbol is
> not found and the only possibility is to load its location from the
> external program database.** The best practice to know more and to get
> symbol files is reading Microsoft's documentation (**you will need
> symbol files for dwmcore.dll and udwm.dll**). The most important thing
> is that the version of the program database must correspond to the
> used DWM library version.

So you have to [manually download the PDBs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/debugging-with-symbols?redirectedfrom=MSDN#getting-the-symbols-you-need) for `dwmcore.dll` and `udwm.dll` with symchk.exe which is part of the Windows SDK or via the tool called [PDB Downloader](https://github.com/rajkumar-rangaraj/PDB-Downloader/releases).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42610/discussion-on-answer-by-magicandre1981-aero-glass-does-not-know-how-to-hook-you).